# why angularJS uses "dirty" ? I only need to know it's "empty"?

Tags: angularjs

it's common to see statements like this:

"myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid"

but if "myForm.user" is empty at first, it's strangely valid!

why angularJS uses "dirty" but not "empty"?

Comment: `dirty` means users has interacted with form/element

Comment: if you don't put presence validation on the field, the empty value is valid value

Comment: don't want all errors showing without ever touching the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular all form inputs are invalid initially and $dirty is false as user has not interacted with the form fields.

To use the validation for empty fields we have to check 3 things
1. $dirty
2. $error.required
3. $invalid

Here is an example

```
<input type="text" name="bookName" ng-model="BookName" ng-maxlength="50" required />
```

If you want to display the message until the user interacted with the field then there is no need to use $dirty, you can check it like this..

```
  <span ng-show="addBookForm.bookName.$invalid && addBookForm.bookName.$error.required">Book name is required.</span>
```

But if you want to display the error message after the user interacted with the field but left it blank then use this.

```
  <span ng-show="addBookForm.bookName.$dirty && addBookForm.bookName.$invalid && addBookForm.bookName.$error.required">Book name is required.</span>
```

So for the validations like format validation, range validations, numeric or alphanumeric validation it is important to check $dirty because all these needs user interaction with fields but for empty field validations $dirty checking can be ignored.

For more help visit below link

http://mrbool.com/the-concepts-of-angularjs-forms/29117

Comment: That's my pleasure. I am glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Initially the form is considered to be valid as the user has not interacted with it and filled anything.

$dirty specifies that the user has interacted with the form. Only then you would want to check for errors.